# StackOverflowError when generating json tree

Tags: java, json, hibernate

Creating online store. I need to generate json that represents category tree, but when Im generating it got StackOverflowError.
Category Entity :

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
private List<Category> subcategories;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
private Category parentCategory;
```

Json generating method, I send List from Controller to represent tree

```
    @Override
public List<Category> getCategoryTree() {
    List<Category> categories = categoryDao.findAll();
    List<Category> roots = categories.stream()
            .filter(category -> category.getParentCategory()!=null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return roots;
}
```

I guess its because child gets parent and parent get child. But i cant place @JsonIgnore annotation because then it will write only list of parents without children or all children without parents, is there must be a way to generate json

Answer (score 0):

resolution was very simple, StackOverflowErrorwas because child was generating paernt and parent generating child, solution was very simple detail, an annotation
@JsonBackReference

Entity :

```
    @OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
private List<Category> subcategories;


@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
private Category parentCategory;
```

Json tree generating method :

```
    @Override
public List<Category> getCategoryTree() {
    List<Category> categories = categoryDao.findAll();
    List<Category> roots = categories.stream()
            .filter(category -> category.getParentCategory()==null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return roots;
}
```